# How to control depth on custom Spring Data Neo4j repository methods?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

For example, if I want to get list of users by name:

```
class UserRepository extands GraphRepository<User> {

    List<User> findByName(String name);
}
```

then how to set loading depth to 2?

I tried to find answer in the [SDN 4.0.0.RC2 docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.0.0.RC2/reference/html/), but it isn't contains anything about this issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Derived finders do not yet support a depth. You'll have to write a custom query or use the `loadAllByProperty` method on the `Neo4jTemplate` if applicable.

This should have been mentioned in the docs, we'll add it.

Comment: It's a pity. In any case, many thanks for the explanation! Can you also clarify whether will it be supported in future or not?

Comment: Yes, it will be, but I cannot say which release. You can track the issue here https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-744

Answer (score 11):

As of SDN [4.2.0-M1](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/4.2.0.M1/changelog.txt), this feature has been implemented. It hasn't made it to the reference documentation at the time of this writing, but see [this PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/commit/2d331a8914a062121c7d33650cb63629d5d44834#diff-2) for implementation, tests and example app updates.

In short, derived finder methods can now sport a `@Depth(n)` annotation to specify a fetch depth of n ([ref](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/2d331a8914a062121c7d33650cb63629d5d44834/spring-data-neo4j/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/examples/movies/repo/CinemaRepository.java#L67)). You can also add a `@Depth`-annotated argument to method signatures that can be used to specify the fetch depth on each call ([ref](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/2d331a8914a062121c7d33650cb63629d5d44834/spring-data-neo4j/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/queries/DerivedQueryTest.java#L455)).

Cheers, @Luanne - this looks great :)